# Slow speeds on Amazon S3 bucket upload

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an Amazon S3 bucket for my media files on my django project. I've enabled Transfer Acceleration on my s3 bucket and I've also changed these settings from this

```
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

to

```
S3_URL = '//%s.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Unfortunately, these changes have made 0 difference when it comes to my upload speed. From where I am, my upload seems to hit 200kb/s, which is fairly slow. I'm on a 330mbit download / 15mbit upload connection.

Questions:

1. Is 200kb/s a good speed for upload to s3?
2. Are there any other obvious or not so obvious things I can check for or change so that my speeds improve?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Theres alot of thing unrelated to network speed that can seriously slow you down. How your uploading it, whcih ssl library you are using, how efficiently you are reading the data all can have an impact. Can you share the code you are using to actually do the upload?

Comment: As an experiment, I just uploaded a large file from home to Amazon S3. I'm on a cable connection in Australia that a speed test says runs at about 10Mbps. The upload to Amazon S3 in the Sydney region ran at about 1.1 MiB/s according to the AWS CLI. I just used the `aws s3 cp` AWS CLI command.

Comment: How far are you from this S3 region?

Comment: do you able to improve the speed? i am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes. The issue wasn't aws or my codebase. It was my host, which was terrible. Speak with your host about upload speeds that you can expect. Prove out those speeds by uploading files via ftp to your server. If those ftp upload speeds are slow, it may be your host. you may have to switch.